# Anything like input() in Module Turtle?

Tags: python, keypress, turtle-graphics, pause, python-turtle

Is there, in module Turtle, a function similar to `input()`, that stops the running of the code until ANY key is pressed?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is not. But you can do this by msvcrt library.

You should first install msvcrt by

```
pip install msvc-runtime
```

then open your python editor, and write the following

```
import msvcrt
def wait():
     msvcrt.getch()
```

Note: This makes the program continue when you press enter and this only works in windows

Example:

```
import msvcrt as ms
def wait():
    ms.getch()

print("hi")
wait()
print("hello")
wait()
print("did it work")
```

this example program prints hi,

then waits the user to press enter,

than prints hello,

then waits for the user to press enter and finally
it prints "did it work"